# Linux, How to integrate icc with eclipse and set icc from evrywhere

Tags: linux, eclipse, intel

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.
I just downloaded and installed Intel parallel studio 2016.

1. If I'm typing icc not from the icc folder, I'm getting error command not found. Is there a way to set icc like gcc (type the icc command from every place I'm running ?)
2. How can I integrate icc and eclipse ?
   I found the following link:
   [enter link description here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-linux-using-intel-compilers-with-the-eclipse-ide-pdf)

But t doest help me (it using icc13 and I cant understand from where I can find the site)

Pls help

Thanks

Comment: Read [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-command-not-found-error-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it/) to solve your first problem, you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

1)In the directory where you installed the compiler (by default that is /opt/intel), you will find a directory composerxe/bin/ . In that directory are scripts compilervars.csh and compilervars.sh. Choose the script that matches your shell and executed that with either the ia32 or the intel64 as an argument - you probably want intel64. This will set up all your environment variables.
2) The files for eclipse support will be in the same place you installed the compilers. So if you installed the compilers in the default location, /opt/intel, then you can use /opt/intel/composerxe (or /opt/intel/composer_xe_) instead of .../composer_xe_2013.0.079.

Comment: Some small corrections: For Parallel Studio 2016 the installation path has changed. Path for icc and compilervars script for root and sudo is in `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin` after installation. More convenient is the path `/opt/intel/bin/`which contains symlinks to all important binaries.

Instead of executing the compilervars script you have to source it at least for bash shell. E.g. `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`